# Divisibility of factorials

Tags: divisibility, factorial

There are two numbers, $n$ and $p$, with prime $p$ and $n < p$. One is to calculate $n! \bmod p$.

Is there any chance of doing this without explicitly determining $n!$ ?

I already know that with $n = p - 1$ then $n! \bmod p = p - 1$. Also if $n = 0$ or $1$, then $n! \bmod p = 1$ (which wasn't hard to see).

The explicit calculations shouldn't be a problem for small $n$, but will become stressful for large $n$.

Comment: What does % represent??

Comment: What does $\mathbin \%$ mean? That is, what operation is $n! \mathbin  \% p$? Division?

Comment: The percent or integral division

Comment: From the property $(p-1)! \mathbin\% p = p-1$, I'd guess it is the remainder from integral division ...

Comment: It is meant to be the modulo operator. Also it shouldn't read faculties but factorials.

Comment: This has some detail:  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/119180/how-to-solve-n-mod-pp-is-a-prime